# chat.stackexchange.com's chat box does not show text as I'm typing in Chrome

Tags: support, chat

When I try to type in something to send, nothing happens. The caret doesn't even blink. However, if I scroll up the page and then back down, suddenly the chat box shows what I typed.

Running Chrome 36.0.1985.143. Is this a known bug or could there be something interfering with the chat box?

Comment: Are you running any extensions? Is this happening if you turn all extensions/plugins off? What OS are you on?

Comment: Also, do you have any chrome flags enabled, such as chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features ?

Comment: On Windows 8.1. I went through each extension 1-by-1 and found the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the extension "ColumnCopy" v0.3.5, which I wouldn't have suspected. It disrupts the chat box.